# Most efficient way of discarding pixel shader calculations with OpenGL ES

Tags: ios, opengl-es, fragment-shader

I have multiple texture reads in my fragment shader, and I am supposedly doing **bad things**, like using the `discard` command and conditionals inside the shader.

The thing is, I am rendering to a texture and I want to reuse it in following passes with other shaders, that do not have to operate on pixels that were previously "discarded". This is for performance. The thing is, I need also to discard calculations if uniforms are out of certain ranges (which I read from another texture): imagine a loop with these shaders running always on the same textures, which are not cleared.

So what I have now, is a terrible performance. One idea I thought about is using `glFragDepth` together with the depth buffer and use that to fire depth testing in order to discard some pixels. But this does not work with the fact I want to have ranges.

Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 2):

You could enable blending, and set the alpha values of pixels you don't want to render to zero. Setup:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

Then in the fragment shader, where you previously called `discard`:

```
...
if (condition) {
    discard;
}
...
```

Set the alpha to zero instead:

```
float alpha = float(condition);
...
gl_FragColor(r, g, b, alpha);
```

Whether this will perform better than discarding pixels could be very system dependent. But if you're looking for alternatives, it's worth trying.